# Automate the API using rest assured

Tags: api

I have got some rest API's for testing with rest assured.

How to automate using with rest assured? What are the different cases that I need to test?

This is a sample API. What are the test cases that I need to test? I want to know about rest API testing concept.

Here is the sample API, what should I do?

```
appinit (GET)
======= 

http://th/m/v2/appinit?
clientId=3&
appName=qberCli



{
"status":true,
"app_secret":"c6b8fff7accd0daf75f1c5757ce11",
"dt":1486100177
}
```

Here is a sample API testing:

```
    package  com.qber.test;

    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

   public class bookToken {
    @Test(dataProvider = "appinit")
    public void md5JsonTest(String clientId,String appName)
 {

        given().
                parameters("c", clientId).parameters("a",appNmae).
                when().
                get("http://th/m/v2/appinit?
    clientId=&
    appName=").
                then().
                assertThat().
                body("md5", equalTo(md5Hash));
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "appinit")
    public Object[][] createMD5TestData() {

        return new String[][] {
                {"3","qbercli"}



        };
    }

}
```

What are the additional test cases that I should write?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of more cases that you need to test, here are some examples:

- get with an invalid client-id, expect error
- get with empty app-name, expect error
- get without passing any query string parameters
- validate that the md5 hash returned is as expected
- validate the payload, that it has 'status' and 'dt' as not-null
- validate the format of the payload data (if it is a string or valid date etc)

I recommend [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) for testing, it is much simpler than REST-Assured. (disclaimer: I am the dev)

Answer (score 0):

If you considering automating API's, I would suggest you to automate it in a traditional way using either

1. Java HttpURLConnection
2. Apache HttpClient

[Please take a look at this link for more info on above 2 points.](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

Comment: I edit my post please review